# Fetching the specific details from table in database with laravel

Tags: php, database, eloquent, laravel-8, project

I wanted to get the details of column member_latitude and member_longitude from a table named member_orders and display them in the blade file.
Here is the snippet of Model class and database table

```
class MemberOrder extends Model{
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'member_name',
    'member_address',
    'member_phone',
    'member_latitude',
    'member_longitude',
    'meal_image',
    'meal_name',
    'meal_type',
    'partner_organizations',
    'partner_address',
    'partner_latitude',
    'partner_longitude',
];
}
```

Any suggestions and answer are welcomed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How does outputting the values from these two fields differ from outputting all the other fields?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get fields in controller and to send them to the view like this:

**Controller content:**

```php
return view('index', ['contents'=>MemberOrder::select('member_latitude','member_longitude')->get()];
```

**Content of view:**

```php
@foreach ($contents as $content)
    <li>Long: {{ $content->member_longitude}}, Lat: {{ $content->member_latitude] }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `->get()` returns a Collection, not a single Model. You would have to use some sort of loop to access `$content->member_latitude`.